Motion One: endDelay property not working
I have made a looping animation using motion one.
I want the animation to loop, but have a pause between the loops.
As far as I understand this can be done using the endDelay property, but it seems to do nothing.
Here is a link to the codepen.

animate(circle,
        {
          scale: 0.8,
          backgroundColor: 'purple',
        },
        { 
          duration: 0.75,
          easing: 'ease-in-out',
          repeat: Infinity,
          direction: 'alternate',
          endDelay: 3
        }
 );

I tried using the endDelay property and it does not add a pause between the repetitions. The regular delay property just adds a delay to the start of the animation, but it loops without pause.
